# Copy warning message when you hover over a WORD in Android Studio using Mac

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

Not sure if this question was already answered in the past but I was not able to find anything on it. I wanted to know if there is a possibility to immediately copy a warning that appears under some "**words**" in Android Studio?

**Example:**
[image]

Is there a Mac keyboard shortcut to copy that 'android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle' message?

Comment: On windows, I can hover my mouse over the warning message, highlight the text, and then while still holding the mouse button down, hit cntrl + c. I would think this would work on the mac by doing the same and then hitting command + c.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Alt+click`(left button of the mouse) on popup copies the whole text. Tested on android studio 3.6 windows 10.

Comment: For mac, maintaining the option clicked, will allow you to highlight the text. Once highlighted: Command + C will copy it.

Answer (score 5):

This is an IntelliJ inherited problem. You can find a workaround [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29710938/1876359).

Basically, click on the error/warning in order to have the cursor on it. Then you will find the same message in the message bar on the bottom. Right-click and copy

Comment: This is actually what I replied to @Rudi Ruessolds in the comments section. As far as the workaround, it is stating that it's for windows machines and not for macs.

Answer (score 4):

I think it is possible to mark it with the mouse and while you still hold the mouse button down press cmd + c.... but in fact this is not a shortcut.

Comment: I actually tried that way and I have also tried the suggestion by @NoChinDeluxe but every time I click on that yellow brownish warning message, the msg disappears. The only way that seems to work for me so far is to do an "Analyze" --> " Code Inspect", then copy that warning message from the results for the inspection Profile.

Comment: @RedM This is the only suggestion that worked for me. I tried it on Linux with Android Studio 3.6.2. They should really implement copying from that popup text bubble. Selecting is already possible, so half of it is already implemented.