# Copy tooltip message into clipboard in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

In Android Studio, is there a setting I can enable that would let me do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29710938/918585)?

Answer (score 1):

Not intuitive at all, nevertheless:

1) click on the underlined word to show the tooltip:

[image: Click on error]

The error will appear on the bottom bar.

2) Right click on that bar on the bottom:

[image: Right-click for copy menu]

The very important trick is to reach the bar with the mouse pointer without hovering on the 'Debug', 'TODO', 'Profiler', etc. buttons that are just above the bar we need to reach.

Comment: Cool workaround to the requires-rep-to-post-images thing. I'm editing the post.

Comment: Honestly: If you figure out how to use JS snippets to cheat the system, you've earned it.

Comment: Unfortunately right clicking does not bring up that menu for me. I should add that I'm using a Mac

Comment: @Vas Left-click?